# double inheritence of ModelForm class, can't change required fields

Tags: django, forms, inheritance, required, modelform

I have a ModelForm class that I use as a parent for all my other form classes. It looks like this:

```
class BootstrapForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BootstrapForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field in self.fields:
            self.fields[field].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control text-center'
            if field != 'email':
                self.fields[field].widget.attrs['class'] += ' text-capitalize'

        for error in self.errors:
            if error in self.fields:
                self.fields[error].widget.attrs['class'] += ' is-invalid'
```

Also I have a model that has a field 'tax_no' with blank set to True:

```
class Institution(CustomModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256,
                            null=False,
                            blank=False,
                            verbose_name=_('nazwa'))
    address = models.ForeignKey('Address',
                                on_delete=models.PROTECT,
                                null=False,
                                blank=False,
                                verbose_name=_('adres'))
    phone = PhoneNumberField(null=True,
                             blank=True,
                             verbose_name=_('telefon'))
    tax_no = models.CharField(max_length=15,
                              null=True,
                              blank=True,
                              validators=[validate_tax_number, ],
                              verbose_name=_('NIP'))
```

What I want is a model that allows empty tax_no field by default but I want a possibility to set it as a required on demand.
My problem is that when I try set the field to required like this:

```
class InvoiceInstitutionForm(BootstrapForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Institution
        exclude = ('address',)

    def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
        super(InvoiceInstitutionForm, self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        print(self.fields['tax_no'].required)
        self.fields['tax_no'].required = True
```

it only works correctly if the InvoiceInstitutionForm inherits directly from forms.ModelForm. It doesn't work when inherited from BootsrapForm class.
What is strange it generates html field correctly:

```
<input type="text" name="invoice-tax_no" maxlength="15" class="form-control text-center text-capitalize" required="" id="id_invoice-tax_no">
```

But it does not care about this when validating. It can be valid even with tax_no empty.
Any ideas why it doesn't work and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do `for error in self.errors:`, accessing `self.errors` causes the form to be validated. This happens when you call `super(InvoiceInstitutionForm, self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)`.

When you set `required = True` on the following line, it's too late because, because the form has already been validated.

I initially suggested that you could use the [`error_css_class`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.error_css_class) option instead of looping through `self.errors`, but as you say in the comments, that will only work if you are using `{{ form.as_p }}`, `{{ form.as_table }}`.

Comment: You're the best! Thanks for taking the time. I completely forgot that self.errors does the validation as well.
I see that it's not possible to use ModelForm with error_css_class.
For now I added my errors the same way I did before just in the is_valid method.

Comment: From what I read yesterday and tested today `error_css_class` only changes the class of a field wrap element not of the input itself. What's more it makes it only while unpacking complete form in template `form.as_p' , table or list.